# Missing file command?

Tags: linux, debian, package-management

I'm running **OpenMediaVault** which is a Debian based Linux distribution and the `file` command is missing.

Is there any way to install it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On a Debian systems `file` can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install file
```

Comment: You can't expect `sudo` to be available on any Debian-based system. The correct answer would be to run `apt-get install file` with root permissions independent on how to reach them (`sudo`, `su -`, `ssh root@localhost`, whatever)

Comment: @XTaran Of course I can expect it to be available. Why would I not be able to expect that? `sudo` might not **be** available, but that doesn't hinder my expectation that it will be. I might not be able to login as root or `sshd` not installed. I can also expect  a keyboard to type something in, but it might not be there. If you could confirm that mediavault would not, by default have `sudo` available, but would have a root password, that is be useful information (for Ubuntu systems based on Debian my experience is that it is the other way around: `sudo` installed, but no default login for root